# Survival Analysis patient recycling

Tags: survival

I have a Survival Analysis problem. In this problem the patient participates with a medicine until this cure is rejected due to inefficacy or adverse effects. Of course the patient can continue until the end of study because the medicine worked for him/her (censoring).

The difference here is that a patient who had adverse effects or the medicine had no efficacy and left the study returns to it with another medicine as new patient.

I would like to ask if this is right from Survival Analysis point of view. Is there any problem with patient recycling in Survival Analysis model? I cannot imagine something especially in Kaplan Meier model. But I am not sure about Cox regression.

Any opinion would be appreciated.